# Simple Angular JS app not working and not showing any errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Simple Angular JS app isn't working. Can anybody help me out, the following is the code. `Index.js` is the main file which includes a script file `controller.js` .

The browser does not shows any errors when I try to run the app:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.name="Angad";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <footer>Copyright-2017</footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you declare 2 controllers ? Plus make sure `angular.min.js` has loaded properly

Comment: Ok remove ng-controller="myCtrl" from body tag

Comment: your code is working fine. How are you testing your app ? Simply by opening `index.html` in a browser ?

Comment: @Weedoze ... Yes by running the file index.html in the browser

Comment: @AngadbirSinghSandhu That's not how to run an AngularJS app. You should launch via a servr

Comment: @Rishabh  I published the controller twice by mistake ... tried running it by including ng-controller once in the file .... still aint working in the browser

Comment: There is the error explaining what's wrong.

Comment: check in browser source if the js files are correctly loaded.

Comment: @Weedoze Used to launch angular dummy apps sometime ago by simply running on browser ... Just wanted to know why it doesnt works this way ..... Can I use a simple python server to run the same  ?

Comment: You code is working. I guess angular JS is not loaded from correct location

Comment: Is your console showing no error? Include your script files in head.

Answer (score 6):

it is due to script loading statement

change

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js" />
<script src="js/controller.js" />
```

with

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks .. I worked :) But I do want to know why it didnt worked the other way around ... I mean whats the diff between <script /> and <script></script> in this context

Comment: <Script> tag is not self closing tag like <input> tag

Answer (score 2):

Simple Angularjs app works without a webserver. 
Your example will also work.

Just close the script tag properly.

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
```